# replace with inverted commas using sed

Tags: php, unix, sed

I would like to replace `,name=` with `"|"`
I am able to replace `,name` with `|` using

```
$commandSed =exec("sed -i 's/,name=/|/g' " . $userPath . "Export.txt");
```

How do I include the inverted commas as well?

```
$commandSed =exec("sed -i 's/,name=/"|"/g' " . $userPath . "Export.txt");
```

This does not work and no replace is done

Thanks

Comment: And where are the "inverted commas" supposed to go?  Are you referring to opening and closing quotation marks, `’` and `”`?  Can you include your attempt so far, your expected output, and what you're getting instead of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably include double quotes inside your double-quoted command line by escaping them with a backslash:

```
$commandSed =exec("sed -i 's/,name=/\"|\"/g' " . $userPath . "Export.txt");
```

However, I would caution that what you're doing here is probably NOT the best way to achieve your real goal, whatever that is.  This sounds suspiciously like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

What's the bigger picture here? What are you *really* trying to do?